# Change default Quick Doc / Documentation hover size in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I've been having a problem with Android Studio for a while where my quick doc hovers are minimized such as the following:

[image: quickDoc minimized]

It would be much nicer if by default it was a larger size, e.g. 
[image]

Does anyone know how to get Android Studio to default to a larger quick doc size? I know you can resize it manually (as I have been doing) and this seems to persist for awhile, but invariably it reverts back occasionally and I have to resize it again. It would be really nice to have it consistently set to a useful size.

I am using Android Studio 0.8.9 beta on OS X 10.10 Yosemite.