# Android Studio change floating doc window to pinned by default

Tags: android, android-studio, settings

When I start Android Studio, settings related to the tooltip / floating doc window seem to revert back to normal. Specifically, I like the right hand side of my IDE to show doc info. However, I don't see settings for the default behavior of this window, just a toggle for turning it on or off.

This related question shows a screenshot of the doc window I speak of, but my window shows full size unlike the poster here: [Change default Quick Doc / Documentation hover size in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495314/change-default-quick-doc-documentation-hover-size-in-android-studio)

What I like to do when opening any Android Studio project for the day is:

1. Hover over something to get the Documentation window to appear (covering the editor window almost entirely)
2. Go to the settings in that popup and UNcheck Floating, while leaving Pinned checked
3. Resize the width of the documentation pane which is now docked on the right like I want

This has been old for quite some time, repeating this step, sometimes being startled when I hover and the whole window pops up in my face. Whether global defaults or per project defaults are available, I'd like to know.

Can I set this default behavior and if so how? I am running Ubuntu or some flavor of linux on the dev PCs, so I am not interested in Windows-only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To change floating window to pinned by default edit the file:
.AndroidStudio2.3\config\options\window.manager.xml

with : `<window_info id="Structure" active="false" anchor="right" auto_hide="true" internal_type="DOCKED" type="DOCKED" visible="false" show_stripe_button="true" weight="0.25" sideWeight="0.5" order="1" side_tool="false" content_ui="tabs" />`

Hope thi helps!